# Ordinal hour-of-day "Hour Ending" conversion to date-time value

Tags: java, sql, datetime, jodatime, java-time

Some businesses track events in time by "hour ending". Each hour of the day is represented by an ordinal number:

- 1…24 for UTC
- 1…23, 1…24, and 1…25 for time zones with a one-hour Daylight Saving Time (DST) adjustment.

So first hour of day, from midnight to 01:00 is `Hour Ending 01`.

To me, it seems like a silly way to track time. More sensible would be using time-of-day by the Half-Open approach, `[)`, where the beginning is inclusive, and ending is exclusive. So:

- `2014-12-05T01:00:00.000` would mark `Hour Ending 01`
- `2014-12-06T00:00:00.000` (midnight) would mark `Hour Ending 24`.

Indeed, that is what I want to store in my database ([Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org)), a [TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Date_and_time) value converted from the date & ordinal hour number. So my question is:

> Given a date and an ordinal "Hour Ending" number (1…23/24/25 for locality with 1-hour DST), how do I convert to a date-time value?

I'm familiar with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Does either of them offer a way to convert? If not, what kind of algorithm handles both the ordinal number conversion and DST?

Or should I not fight this, and just store the local date as a string with a suffix of the ordinal hour number?

Comment: You don't actually need java.time or Joda for this.  Can't you just use an ordinary `Calendar` object, set the day, month and year, set it to midnight, then add on the right number of hours?  That will work at the start and end of daylight savings.

Comment: @DavidWallace As a policy, I avoid the mess that is java.util.Date/.Calendar. But your idea seems sound and strikingly simple. Joda-Time has the method `withTimeAtStartOfDay` to get first moment of day. The method `plusHours` could use the "Hour Ending" number to arrive at a date-time value. For conversions from date+hourEnding to date-time, that should work. Going the other way, I'm not sure.

Comment: Going the other way, you just have to take the difference in hours between the given time, and midnight on the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the `java.time` method you are looking for is [truncatedTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-), which can be used to take any `ZonedDateTime` and truncate the minutes and seconds

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime rounded = zdt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
ZonedDateTime hourEnd = rounded.plusHours(1);
```